# JavaFX context menu item group

Tags: java, javafx, contextmenu, menuitem

I want to set visibility of some (not all) context menu items inside the same context menu without having to explicitly set visibility of each of them as that seems like a lot of boilerplate code. Is there any way to have a common container or something similar for these menu items, so that I can simply set the visibility of this container? I've googled for a bit but found nothing related so far.

I'm thinking about giving these menu items the same css class then creating 2 style sheets that define the behaviour of this class, one with `visibility:visible` and the other `visibility:hidden`, then I can dynamically load the style sheets to suit my need. I believe this could work but it seems a bit hacky for my taste. I would prefer a more normal way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Bind their visibility properties to a single, separate property.

```
private final BooleanProperty selectionItemsVisible =
    new SimpleBooleanProperty();

// ...

    cutMenuItem.visibleProperty().bind(selectionItemsVisible);
    copyMenuItem.visibleProperty().bind(selectionItemsVisible);
    saveSelectionMenuItem.visibleProperty().bind(selectionItemsVisible);

    // ...

    selectionItemsVisible.set(true);
```

Comment: This is indeed better than my CSS approach. I would still prefer a common parent approach though. I mean what if I want other behaviours that are shared between the menu items such as dragging or removing them as a group. Do you have any suggestions?